# NSPredicate with localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare

Tags: core-data, nspredicate, case-sensitive

I have an App with CoreData and I need to use NSPredicate to retrieve all the contacts from a city.

The question is that "city" maybe written like LONDON or London or even london. And the user will type London to search, or LoNDon.

What I need is to use NSPredicate with localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare, so that all the records are retrieved.

Code:

```
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                         @"activityDeleted == %@ && (SUBQUERY(hasMembers, $sub, $sub.memberDeleted == %@).@count > 0) && (SUBQUERY(hasMembers, $sub, $sub.city == %@)", 
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], 
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],
                         city];
```

The above NSPredicate retrieves all the groups that have Contacts, not deleted, that are in a certain City, but I have the CaseInsensitive problem...

How can I do that?

Thanks,

RL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need subquery here.  Your entire predicate can instead be:

```
@"activityDeleted == NO AND ANY hasMembers.memberDeleted = NO AND ANY hasMembers.city =[cd] %@", city
```

Comment: by not using SUBQUERY, i have performance issues. It's a lot fast if use SUBQUERY.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the case insensitive and diacritic insensitive modifiers "[cd]" on the ==

```
SUBQUERY(hasMembers, $sub, $sub.city ==[cd] %@)
```

You might try searching stackoverflow for "case insensitive nspredicate" there are several answers already https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=case+insensitive+nspredicate